# Testing ValueTask method with FluentAssertions, should not throw

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-assertions, valuetask

I'm a bit confused here. I'm using *FluentAssertions* and I have this test method:

```
    [Test]
    public void DoNothingWhenEmpty()
    {
        FileCleanUpProcessor fileProcessor = new();
        Func<ValueTask> act = () => fileProcessor.ProcessCommands();
        act.Should().NotThrow();
    }
```

The MUT signature is the following:

```
public async ValueTask ProcessCommands() { ... }
```

While it works (I guess), I wonder if I've written this correctly. And why method `NotThrowAsync()` is not available/not implemented for `ValueTask`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

> While it works (I guess), I wonder if I've written this correctly

Given that the subject under test is asynchronous then it stands to reason that the test should be async as well.

```
[Test]
public async Task DoNothingWhenEmpty() {
    //Arrange
    FileCleanUpProcessor fileProcessor = new();

    //Act
    Func<Task> act = async () => await fileProcessor.ProcessCommands();

    //Assert
    await act.Should().NotThrowAsync();
}
```

> And why method `NotThrowAsync()` is not available/not implemented for `ValueTask`

`NotThrowAsync()` was defined for either `Task` or `Task<TResult>` and as such is not available for `ValueTask`

Reference [FluentAssertions : Exceptions](https://fluentassertions.com/exceptions/)

Comment: No, that's why I asked this question specifically about `ValueTask`.